Android notifications: Disable ability to click on multiple notifications at once
I send notifications via Firebase. When the user clicks on a single notification, everything is working fine. However, when there are multiple notifications from my app, they group up and when a user clicks on that group, it just opens my app, but the actions setup for the notifications don't trigger.
How can I listen to the user clicking on a group of notifications? The click does not trigger:
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {

Is there a way to disable the grouping all together? Because once the group is clicked, all notifications are gone. In my case that means that some information (and the possibility of the user to react to it) is lost.

Hope this link helps you in managing group notifications https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/group
